# how to convert a field to string in a mysql join

Tags: mysql, mariadb

I try to join a filed that is a int(13) on to a field that is varchar(50).

If I only use `(a.id = b.id)` the DESCRIBE says type: ref.

If I use `(a.id = CONCAT(b.id))` the DESCRIBE says type: eq_ref. (where b.id is the integer)

The use of `CONCAT` to cast a field is ugly, so I tried to use `CAST()` or `CONVERT()`.

If I use `(a.id = CAST(b.id AS CHAR(50)))` the DESCRIBE says type: ref.

How do I write a correct cast/convert, that gives a eq_ref join?

UPDATE 1:

DESCRIBE SELECT.. with CONCAT

```
+------+-------------+-----------------------+--------+-----------------------------------+----------------+---------+-------------------------------------+------+----------------------------------------+
| id   | select_type | table                 | type   | possible_keys                     | key            | key_len | ref                                 | rows | Extra                                  |
+------+-------------+-----------------------+--------+-----------------------------------+----------------+---------+-------------------------------------+------+----------------------------------------+
|    1 | SIMPLE      | ext_icecat_prodmatch  | ref    | PRIMARY,our_article_id,product_id | our_article_id | 152     | const                               | 3016 | Using index condition; Using temporary |
|    1 | SIMPLE      | ext_icecat_product    | eq_ref | PRIMARY,product_id                | PRIMARY        | 4       | ext_icecat_prodmatch.product_id     |    1 |                                        |
|    1 | SIMPLE      | ext_icecat_supplier   | eq_ref | PRIMARY                           | PRIMARY        | 4       | ext_icecat_product.supplier_id      |    1 |                                        |
|    1 | SIMPLE      | products              | eq_ref | PRIMARY                           | PRIMARY        | 152     | ext_icecat_prodmatch.our_article_id |    1 |                                        |
|    1 | SIMPLE      | partner_product_saved | eq_ref | PRIMARY                           | PRIMARY        | 155     | const,func                          |    1 | Using where                            |
|    1 | SIMPLE      | category_names        | eq_ref | PRIMARY                           | PRIMARY        | 6       | products.category_id,const          |    1 | Using where                            |
+------+-------------+-----------------------+--------+-----------------------------------+----------------+---------+-------------------------------------+------+----------------------------------------+
```

The Select:

```
SELECT
    partner_product_saved.*,
    ext_icecat_product.product_id,
    CONCAT(ext_icecat_supplier.name, ' ', ext_icecat_product.name) AS export_product_name,
    ext_icecat_product.catid_match AS category_id,
    GROUP_CONCAT(ext_icecat_prodmatch.our_article_id) AS oais,
    products.file_name,
    category_names.category_path 
FROM ext_icecat_product
    LEFT JOIN ext_icecat_prodmatch USING (product_id)
    LEFT JOIN ext_icecat_supplier USING (supplier_id)
    LEFT JOIN products USING (our_article_id)
    LEFT JOIN partner_product_saved ON (partner_product_saved.partner_id = 29 AND partner_product_saved.product_id = CONCAT(ext_icecat_product.product_id))
    LEFT JOIN category_names ON (category_names.category_id = products.category_id AND category_names.language_id = 2) 
WHERE ext_icecat_prodmatch.our_article_id = '0EF03850-D25A-1174-BCDC-EC67352010A6' 
GROUP BY ext_icecat_product.product_id 
ORDER BY NULL;
```

SHOW CREATE TABLE

```
CREATE TABLE `partner_product_saved` (
  `partner_id` mediumint(8) NOT NULL,
  `product_id` varchar(50) CHARACTER SET utf8 NOT NULL,
  `product_name` varchar(100) CHARACTER SET utf8 NOT NULL,
  `our_article_id` varchar(50) CHARACTER SET utf8 DEFAULT NULL,
  `our_category_id` mediumint(8) DEFAULT NULL,
  `manufacture_id` mediumint(8) DEFAULT NULL,
  `manufacturer_partnr` varchar(255) COLLATE utf8_bin NOT NULL,
  `manufacturer_upc` varchar(255) COLLATE utf8_bin NOT NULL,
  `image` tinytext COLLATE utf8_bin NOT NULL,
  `image_small` tinytext COLLATE utf8_bin NOT NULL,
  `image_big` tinytext COLLATE utf8_bin NOT NULL,
  `image_200` tinytext COLLATE utf8_bin NOT NULL,
  `image_original` tinytext COLLATE utf8_bin NOT NULL,
  `image_width` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `image_height` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `birth` timestamp NOT NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,
  `last_updated` timestamp NULL DEFAULT NULL,
  `saved` tinyint(3) unsigned NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  PRIMARY KEY (`partner_id`,`product_id`),
  KEY `our_article_id` (`our_article_id`),
  KEY `our_category_id` (`our_category_id`),
  KEY `manufacture_id` (`manufacture_id`,`manufacturer_partnr`),
  KEY `manufacturer_upc` (`manufacturer_upc`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 COLLATE=utf8_bin;

CREATE TABLE `ext_icecat_product` (
  `product_id` int(13) NOT NULL,
  `supplier_id` int(13) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  `prod_id` varchar(235) COLLATE utf8_bin NOT NULL DEFAULT '',
  `prod_id_clean` varchar(255) CHARACTER SET utf8 NOT NULL,
  `catid` int(13) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  `catid_match` varchar(50) CHARACTER SET utf8 NOT NULL,
  `name` varchar(255) CHARACTER SET utf8 NOT NULL,
  `name_clean` varchar(255) CHARACTER SET utf8 NOT NULL,
  `low_pic` varchar(255) COLLATE utf8_bin NOT NULL DEFAULT '',
  `high_pic` varchar(255) COLLATE utf8_bin NOT NULL DEFAULT '',
  `thumb_pic` varchar(255) COLLATE utf8_bin DEFAULT NULL,
  `family_id` int(13) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  `low_pic_size` int(13) DEFAULT '0',
  `high_pic_size` int(13) DEFAULT '0',
  `thumb_pic_size` int(13) DEFAULT '0',
  `import_date` datetime NOT NULL,
  `release_date` datetime NOT NULL,
  `updated` datetime NOT NULL,
  `need_update` tinyint(1) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  `deleted` tinyint(1) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  `keyword` tinyint(1) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  `special_match` tinyint(1) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  PRIMARY KEY (`product_id`),
  KEY `supplier_id` (`supplier_id`),
  KEY `catid` (`catid`),
  KEY `prod_id` (`prod_id`),
  KEY `product_id` (`product_id`,`prod_id`,`supplier_id`),
  KEY `release_Date` (`release_date`),
  KEY `prod_id_clean` (`prod_id_clean`),
  KEY `name_clean` (`name_clean`),
  KEY `need_update` (`need_update`),
  KEY `deleted` (`deleted`),
  KEY `keyword` (`keyword`),
  KEY `catid_2` (`catid`,`import_date`),
  KEY `catid_match` (`catid_match`),
  KEY `special_match` (`special_match`)
) ENGINE=MyISAM DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 COLLATE=utf8_bin;
```

Comment: What exactly is the problem with using `(a.id = b.id)`?

Comment: My guess its converting the VARCHAR to an INT, and therefor can't use the index

Comment: Have you benchmarked (a.id = b.id) v (a.id = CONCAT(b.id))?

Comment: `SHOW PROCESSLIST` shows only that query and 'Query for 63s, Copying to tmp table' and counting, and with CONCAT its done in 0.33s

Comment: the descirbe for CONCAT is type:eq_ref, rows:1, and for = or CAST it's type:ref, rows:35614

Comment: "Can't use index" applies to `CONCAT`, `CONVERT`, `CONV`, `CAST`, and anything else.  Please provide `SHOW CREATE TABLE` and the `SELECT`; There may be something else we could recommend.

Comment: @RickJames it uses the index when using CONCAT, as I get a "eq_ref", but with simple `=` or CAST() its only gets "ref", added DESCRIBE, SELECT, and SHOW CREATE TABLE.

Comment: In all your experiments, did `EXPLAIN` show a different order of hitting the tables?

Comment: No, always the same order, only change is that eq_ref becomes ref, and rows go from 1 to 35614

Answer (score -1):

`WHERE indexed_column = any_function(any_column)` -- can use index. `WHERE non_indexed_column = any_function(indexed_column)` -- cannot use index.

The difference between `ref` and `eq_ref` is minor. I think that `eq_ref` is where the optimizer decides that there cannot be more than one match, often because of UNIQUE.

`WHERE ext_icecat_prodmatch.our_article_id = '0EF03850-D25A-1174-BCDC-EC67352010A6'` -- is `our_article_id` `INDEXed`? or `UNIQUE`?  Sounds like it is only an `INDEX`, so multiple rows might ensue.  To make it `eq_ref`, you need `UNIQUE`.  But only if the data supports such.  The stats imply there might be 3016 rows with that article_id.

Do not use `LEFT` unless you need it.  Note how the Optimizer turned `LEFT JOIN ext_icecat_prodmatch USING (product_id)` into `JOIN` and decided (rightly) to start with `ext_icecat_prodmatch`.

Back to other discussions...

```
AND partner_product_saved.product_id = CONCAT(ext_icecat_product.product_id))
```

can go one way, but not the other.  That is, it can efficiently go from eip to pps, but not the other way.  And `EXPLAIN` indicated such with `const,func`.

Comment: "is our_article_id INDEXed?", if you read the explain, that row is "ref" and have 3016rows, using the key our_article_id, so yes its an index, and not realy the part of the problem. Using "LEFT JOIN" is mostly just lazyness, as i use `implode(" LEFT JOIN ", $tables)` to create the query, but the optiomer always solves that correct.

Comment: "can go one way, but not the other.", yes, the same way as `AND partner_product_saved.product_id = CAST(ext_icecat_product.product_id) AS CHAR)`